# Defining fmap for a RoseTree

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write a `Functor` instance for RoseTree datatype.

```
data Rose a = MkRose a [Rose a]
    deriving (Eq, Show)
```

```hs
instance Functor Rose where

fmap f (MkRose a children) = MkRose (f a) (fmap f children)
```

I really thought this would work but I get :

```
Expected type: [a]

Actual type: [Rose a]
```

for children, could anyone explain to me where I went wrong?

Comment: Please provide your `data` definition of `Rose`

Comment: Forgot to, just added it, thank you.

Comment: `fmap f (MkRose a children) = MkRose (f a) (map (fmap f) children)`
Could someone explain why this worked? What does mapping (fmap f) do?

Comment: `fmap f` works on _one_ `Rose a`, while `map (fmap f)` works on `[Rose a]`.

Comment: Look at my answer with `fmap . fmap`. This is effectively the same as `fmap . map` in this case since you are `fmap`ing over a list and the same as `(map (fmap f) children)`. The reason is that you are dealing with 2 structures, a list and Rose so you need to drill down to get to the values.

Answer (score 1):

```hs
data Rose a = MkRose a [Rose a]
    deriving (Eq, Show)


instance Functor Rose where
  fmap f (MkRose a []) = MkRose (f a) []
  fmap f (MkRose a roses) = MkRose (f a) ((fmap . fmap) f roses)
```

The problem you are facing is due to the fact that the children of `Rose` are packed away in an additional data structure, namely the list `[]`. So you have a recursive data structure that at each step has infinitely many branches, e.g. recursion paths. In other words, it's not one path like in a list, it's not only 2 or three paths like in a binary tree or similar where the branches are normally named with specific data constructors, but each node can have infinitely many children.

So, you need to drill down to access the values you are seeking by using an `fmap . fmap` construct. The right `fmap` (for which there is a built-in `Functor` provided by the ghc, goes over each element of the list and passes them over to the left `fmap` which drills into the `MkRose` values for which you have written the `Functor`.

If you look at the signature of `fmap` you have:

```hs
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

Applying this to `[]` gives:

```hs
fmap @[] :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

This is the signature of the right `fmap` in `fmap . fmap` in our case.

Similarly, applying `fmap` to `Rose` gives the signature:

```hs
fmap @Rose :: (a -> b) -> Rose a -> Rose b
```

The composition of these 2 guys gives the output of the right one as input to the left one and the left one acts with `f` on its input which are roses.

Answer (score 0):

When `f :: a -> b`, `fmap f` has type `F a -> F a` for any one functor `F` of our choice. For example, we might use it as

```
fmap f :: [a] -> [b]
fmap f :: Rose a -> Rose b   -- in recursive calls
fmap f :: Maybe a -> Maybe b
fmap f :: IO a -> IO b
...
```

You get the point, I think. However, if we have *two* functors, then `fmap f` alone does not suffice. For instance we do NOT have

```
fmap f :: Maybe [a] -> Maybe [b]
```

because `fmap` only works with a single functor, while here we have two (`Maybe` and `[]`). If we need to work with nested functors, we need to `fmap` more:

```
f             :: a -> b
fmap f        :: [a] -> [b]               -- add []
fmap (fmap f) :: Maybe [a] -> Maybe [b]   -- add Maybe
```

In your case, you need something of type `[Rose a] -> [Rose b]`, which involves two functors, so you also have to `fmap` twice.